# Why does Intent.ACTION_MAIN require android.permission.MANAGE_USERS on some devices?

Tags: android

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

The above code occasionally throws the following exception:

```
Class: java.lang.SecurityException
 Stack trace: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity } from ProcessRecord{bbef452 4630:net.my.app/u0a5} (pid=4630, uid=10005) requires android.permission.MANAGE_USERS
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3755)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4599)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:2)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4557)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:1)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4918)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4886)
```

This is the case only on a small number of devices. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: That appears to be a first-generation Kindle Fire. Since Amazon does not use the Play Store or Play Services, Amazon can do what it wants, and that may include not allowing third-party apps to start a launcher. In this case, `com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity` feels like it is not even a launcher, but rather a one-time "out of box experience" activity. Why they tied that to the launcher `Intent` is anyone's guess, and that device is 10 years old at this point.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment should be the answer. It is an Android 9 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity that you are trying to start is `com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity`.

A quick search engine lookup suggests that "otter" was the first-generation Kindle Fire. That may not be accurate, in that you believe this device runs Android 9, and that Fire is a ten-year-old device. So, already, this scenario is weird.

If this truly is an Amazon Fire device of some form, they are not governed by the Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) that controls manufacturers that wish to ship the Play Store and Play Services. So, there is no requirement that they have a launcher that is available through an `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` `Intent`, or one that can be started by arbitrary apps.

In this specific case, `com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity` feels like a one-time "out of box experience" activity, not a real launcher. Why this device has that tied to `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` is unclear.

If you are not doing so already, wrap your `startActivity()` call in a `try`/`catch`, so the `SecurityException` does not crash your app. If you are distributing your app through the Amazon AppStore for Android, you might see if they have documentation for a Fire-specific `Intent` for getting to the launcher. Otherwise, you will have to settle for "gracefully degrading" when this situation occurs.

Comment: Thank you. It is a Japanese version of KFONWI and the user somehow managed to download the app from Google Play.